# nvprof to open trace format or slog2

Tags: cuda, profiling, trace, nvvp

I want to generate trace of my cuda program and view it. so I run it using following command

```
nvprof --print-gpu-trace ./my_exec
```

Which prints the trace in text format which has its own limitations to understand. It has been mentioned that I can save the output into a text file and later that can be viewed using nvvp through X session or locally.

To add to my misery, none of existing nvvp installation works in the remote host for myriad reasons. In my local mac, when I install, god only knows where it gets installed which remains *untracable* by "finder". Thus arises my need for, converting the output of nvprof to something which can be displayed by jumpshot (which is also used by TAU), which may be OTC opentrace format or slog2 (native jumshot format).

Ultimately I seek, a visual representation of execution trace any mean possible.

Comment: On your Mac, nvvp should have been installed in `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.5/bin/nvvp` (for v5.5, the current production release).

Comment: Almost certainly, your easiest path will be to figure out where `nvvp` is on your mac and use that. `nvvp` should be in `/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-5.5/bin`, and if you have done a [proper mac install](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-getting-started-guide-for-mac-os-x/index.html), that directory location should have already been added to your `PATH` variable.  If you're not using CUDA 5.5, please identify the version you are using.

Comment: Do you have an actual question here?

Comment: My question was if there are tools to convert output of nvprof trace to other formats. However, consensus seems to use nvvp instead trying converting it to other format

Comment: were you able to locate `nvvp` ?

Comment: Yes. I think there was some problem with previous installation. I installed again. Now I'm able to open nvvp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ultimately I seek, a visual representation of execution trace any mean possible.

The easiest way to do this will be with `nvvp`.

The [documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/index.html#import-nvprof-session) describes how to import an `nvprof` session.

Basically, you need to run `nvprof` with the `--output-profile` option. 
Then import the resultant file using the `nvvp` import wizard (nvvp ... File... Import...)